# Mongoose findOneandUpdate not saving. I assume it's because I'm deleting an object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm deleted one of the stores from Company.store. Everything works fine and res.jsonp(updatedCompany); is returning the correct document. In the response, the store has been deleted. But then I reload the page and the store I tried deleting is still there. Is this because findOneandUpdate doesn't delete anything when it updates?

```
Company.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.body._id
}, {
    store: req.body.store
}, function (err, updatedCompany) {

    res.jsonp(updatedCompany);
});
```

It doesn't make sense because updatedCompany is exactly what I want the document to be, but it's not saving the document... just sending the response I want and not updating the document.

Update: My save isn't working for more than one store either. If I make a new user and add a store, that works fine. If I try to add a second store, it doesn't work.

Here's the object in the user model for store:

```
store: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store'
}],
```

Here's the controller to delete the store:

```
    $scope.delStore = function () {

        Companies.get({
            companyId: $scope.global.user.company
        }, function (company2) {


            var newCompany = new Companies(company2);
            console.log($scope.radio.delStore.name);

            for (var i in $scope.something111.company2.store) {
                if (newCompany.store[i].name === $scope.radio.delStore.name) {
                    newCompany.store.splice(i, 1);

                    newCompany.$update(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });


                }
            };

        });

    };
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Can you post the code you are using for delete?  It seems that your delete is not working since when you refresh the page the document is still present.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post more code.

Comment: My save function used to let me add as many stores as I wanted. At first, when the user was created, I put a single store id in there, referencing another store document. Then I could add as many store ids as I wanted and populate them. But when I don't create a store in the user right away, it only let's me add 1 store maximum.

Comment: Your `$scope.delStore` is not deleting a store... it is updating a store.  You need to use the mongoose remove method instead.

Comment: Why won't it let me add more than one store object to the array all of a sudden?